# writing Algorithm in Latex

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic

I want a Latex code that will write the following algorithm using `\begin{algorithm}` and `\begin{algorithmic}`. I have done this

```
\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
```

but dont know hoe to get others like initialize..

**Input:**

```
f: the function to optimize
ps: the swarm size
d: the problem dimension
```

**Output**:

```
x*: the best fitness value found
```

**Initialize**:

```
x_i = (x$_{i1}$,$\cdots$, x_{id}) and v_{i} = (v_{i1}, $\cdots$, $v_{id}$), for all particles in problem space
evaluate f(x_i) in d variables and get pbest_i, (i = 1, $\cdots$, ps) 
gbest $\gets$ best of pbest_i
```

**calculate V_max using equation (7)**

```
**While** stopping criteria is false do

     Begin Loop for ps times
        Begin Loop for d times
            **update v_i for particle using equation (4)**
            validate for velocity boundaries using V_max
        End
        **generate \tau**
        **update x_i for particle using equation (5) or equation (6)** 
        validate for position boundaries
End

If f(x_i) < f(pbest_i) then 

      pbest_i $\gets$  x_i 
end if

If f(x_i) < f(gbest_i) then 

gbest_i $\gets$ x_i 

end if

**End while**

x* $\gets$ gbest 

Return x*
```

End PSO Algorithm